# How do i get data from two tables using single query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, with the following columns:

- **`OneRecord`**: `team1`, `team2`, `id`
- **`fixture_list`**: `team1`, `team2`, `photo1`, `photo2`

I want to retrieve `photo1`,`photo2` from `fixture_list`, **if** `team1` and `team2` have the same value on both tables.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
<?php
 //checking if the script received a post request or not 
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
     //Getting post data 
     $email=$_POST['email'];
     require_once('connect.php');
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM OneRecord, fixture_list
             WHERE OneRecord.email='$email', 
                   OneRecord.team1=fixture_list.team1_name 
             AND 
                   OneRecord.team2=fixture_list.team2_name";

     $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
     $result = array();

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
         array_push($result, array(
            'team1'=>$row[3],
            'team2'=>$row[4],
            'rs'=>$row[6],
            'team1_score'=>$row[7],
            'team1_wicket'=>$row[8],
            'team2_score'=>$row[10],
            'team2_wicket'=>$row[11],
            'tournament'=>$row[13]
         ));
     }
     echo json_encode (array("bets_list"=>$result));
     mysqli_close($con);

  }

 ?>
```

this is edited question

```
<?php
  //checking if the script received a post request or not 
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

  //Getting post data 
   $email=$_POST['email'];

 require_once('connect.php'); 
 $sql = "SELECT f.team1_photo as "team1_photo",
 f.team2_photo as "team2_photo" FROM OneRecord o INNER JOIN fixture_list f 
 ON 
 o.team1=f.team1_name AND o.team2=f.team2_name WHERE o.email='$email'";

 $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 $result = array();

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
  array_push($result,
  array('team1'=>$row[3],'team2'=>$row[4],
 'rs'=>$row[6],'team1_score'=>$row[7],'team1_wicket'=>$row[8],
 'team2_score'=>$row[10],
 'team2_wicket'=>$row[11],'tournament'=>$row[13],'photo1'=>$row[0],
 'photo2'=>$row[1],
  ));
    }
   echo json_encode (array("bets_list"=>$result));
  mysqli_close($con);

   }

   ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do an inner join of these 2 tables on `team1` and `team2`.

```
SELECT f.photo1 as "photo1",f.photo2 as "photo2", 
FROM OneRecord o 
INNER JOIN fixture_list f
ON o.team1 = f.team1 and o.team2 = f.team2
where o.email = $email;
```

**UPDATE** - If you want all columns, do `select * from ...`.

Comment: how do i get it into the array ,this part                                                                           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
         array_push($result, array(
            'team1'=>$row[3],
            'team2'=>$row[4],
            'rs'=>$row[6],
            'team1_score'=>$row[7],
            'team1_wicket'=>$row[8],
            'team2_score'=>$row[10],
            'team2_wicket'=>$row[11],
            'tournament'=>$row[13]
         ));
     }

Comment: look what i am asking i have to add the data inside the array so how do i differenciate between them and save them

Comment: I hope you understand the question

Comment: @VipulSingh Not getting you. Can you please edit your post and provide a sample  output of what you are looking for?

Comment: the entire data has to be saved inside array

Comment: @VipulSingh `print_r($row)` inside `while` loop and see what you are getting.

Comment: @VipulSingh glad to help.